# Apex Developer Guide Gone?

Tags: apex, documentation

Does anyone know what happened to the Apex Developer guide? I just woke up one day and the now my Apex Developer Guide bookmark started bringing me to a really un-useful site...www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the same site  [www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm)  u will see pdf download on the left side to download apex developer guide.

[image]

or

Go to this [link](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf) to download apex developer guide

Comment: Thanks sf.dev do you think it is nearly as useable?

Comment: Nope, I reckon it's harder to use. Esp the navigation on the left is much more cramped and difficult to see

Answer (score 0):

The PDF version is available at https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf